# Выравнивание с помощью flex

Tags: html, css

Не могу разобраться почему justify-content не выравнивает элементы... 
Хочу выровнить элементы по центру(две стрелки и картинка), но не получается. Может я не вижу чего-то особенного... Буду очень благодарен за помощь в нахождение ошибки.

```css
.modal-big-img { 
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0; 
 padding: 15px; 
 background-color: rgba(27, 31, 34, 0.95);
 visibility: hidden;
 opacity: 0;
 z-index: 10; }
.wrapper-big-img{ 
 display: flex; 
 justify-content: flex-start; 
 align-items: center; }
.arrow { padding: 0 10px; background: red; }
.modal-big-img__img { 
 padding: 30px; 
 box-sizing: border-box; 
 max-width: 800px ; 
 margin: auto; }
.model-big-img__count { text-align: center; }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.modal-big-img__img { ... margin: auto; ... }
```

Не дает, так как это левую стрелку прижимает к левому краю, а правую к правому. [Здесь](https://ejz.ru/139/flex-margin-auto) можно почитать.

Comment: Спасибо. От старой идеи margin остался. Все работает теперь.